# Simple Python method taking forever to execute/run

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

My code gets stuck at the `clean_up()` method in `MyClass()`

**my_class.py:**

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2, pymysql, pyodbc
from db_credentials_dict import db_credentials

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, from_database, to_table_name, report_name):
        ...

    def get_sql(self):
        ...

    def get_connection(self):
        ...

    def query_to_csv(self):
        ...

    def csv_to_postgres(self):
        ...

    def extract_and_load(self):
        self.query_to_csv()
        self.csv_to_postgres()

    def get_final_sql(self):
        ...

    def postgres_to_csv(self):
        ...

    def clean_up(self):
        print('\nTruncating {}...'.format(self.to_table_name), end='')
        with self.postgres_connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM %s)" % self.to_table_name)
            empty = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            if not empty:
                cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE %s" % self.to_table_name)
        self.postgres_connection.commit()
        print('DONE')

        print('Removing {}...'.format(self.filename), end='')
        if os.path.exists(self.filepath):
            os.remove(self.filepath)
            print('DONE')
        else:
            print('{} does not exist'.format(self.filename))
```

**main.py:**

```py
from my_class import MyClass
from time import sleep

bookings = MyClass(from_database='...',to_table_name='...',report_name='...')
bookings2 = MyClass(from_database='...',to_table_name='...',report_name='...')
channel = MyClass(from_database='...',to_table_name='...',report_name='...')
cost = MyClass(from_database='...',to_table_name='...',report_name='...')

tables = [bookings, bookings2, channel, cost]
for table in tables:
    table.extract_and_load()

daily_report = MyClass(from_database='...',to_table_name='...',report_name='...')
daily_report.postgres_to_csv()
sleep(10)

for table in tables:
    table.clean_up()
```

When I run `main.py` it runs everything up until the final loop i.e. `for table in tables: table.clean_up()`. It just gets stuck there, no errors or warnings.

When running that method its own, it works fine i.e. it truncates the postgres tables. Need help getting this to work and understanding why the final method doesn't execute when all others are executed.

**Output of when running `clean_up()` on its own:**

```
Truncating bookings...DONE
Removing bookings.csv...DONE

Truncating bookings2...DONE
Removing bookings2.csv...DONE

Truncating channel...DONE
Removing channel.csv...DONE

Truncating cost...DONE
Removing cost.csv...DONE
```

**What the overall code does:**

1. Grabbing files that contain sql queries extracting data from different databases and executing those queries.
2. Exporting them to csv
3. Importing csv's to a postgres database
4. Writing a postgres query that brings data together and then exports as a csv to be used in a BI tool for data visualisation
5. Truncating the data in postgres and deleting the csv files in point 2

You're probably thinking that this is a madness and I agree. I'm currently making due with what I've got and can't store data on my computer because it's company data (hence the truncating and removing of the data).

Comment: I can't see anything causing this issue in what you posted of your Python code, so the issue is very probably with postgres indeed.

Comment: can you post the output of your clean_up() method when running its own?

Answer (score 5):

`TRUNCATE` clause in Postgres requires `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the relation and also may fire some `BEFORE TRUNCATE` triggers.

My guess is that problem is on the Postgres side, e.g. `TRUNCATE` tries to acquire `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the relation, but it is already locked by someone else.

First, check your Postgres logs.

Next, check what your Postgres backends are doing during your hanged `TRUNCATE` with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Next, investigate locks with:

```sql
-- View with readable locks info and filtered out locks on system tables
CREATE VIEW active_locks AS
SELECT clock_timestamp(), pg_class.relname, pg_locks.locktype, pg_locks.database,
       pg_locks.relation, pg_locks.page, pg_locks.tuple, pg_locks.virtualtransaction,
       pg_locks.pid, pg_locks.mode, pg_locks.granted
FROM pg_locks JOIN pg_class ON pg_locks.relation = pg_class.oid
WHERE relname !~ '^pg_' and relname <> 'active_locks';

-- Now when we want to see locks just type
SELECT * FROM active_locks;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I created the view as you've shown, the output is empty

Comment: OK, what is with pg_stat_activity? What other backends are doing? E.g. with `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE backend_type = 'client backend' AND datname IS NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to do the desired clean process all in one transaction. To Prevent undesired states.

And check If table exists in the database using the information_schema

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'schema_name'
   AND    table_name = 'table_name'
   );
```

Check If exists, create your truncate commands.

and execute the clean  process all in one transaction.